# Yii - два типа пользователей

Tags: yii, users

Как организовать на сайте в дивжке yii два типа пользователей?

Например:

1. Обычные пользователи сайта: клиенты, просто гости и т.д.
2. Модераторы, администраторы сайта, менеджеры по работае с клиентами

Кстати, сразу оговорюсь, что метод не front-end -> back-end. Если тривиально выражаться, то тольо фронт!) Это связано с тем, что админка почти полностью все дублирует, спрашивается тогда: нафига она нужна?

Comment: И еще: пользователи разделены по сущностям, потому как без этого ну никак нельзя. Не хочется давать им одну таблицу.

Comment: Не хочется давать им одну таблицу. Взываю к вашей логике, пользователь он и в Африке пользователь, будь то админ, модератор, гость, сосед Вася - неважно... ИМХО - по нормальному пользователи должны быть в одной таблице.

Comment: Правильно рассуждаете, но на деле всегда две таблицы. Первая с пользователями, вторая с обслуживающими систему юзверями. Как бы выразиться то правильно... Мммм.  в Общем эти пользователи являются разными классами (если в теории ооп) и у них свои наборы правил поведения. Общее у них только логин и пароль, что не является причиной создания общей сущности (в довесок, логины и пароли - разную смысловую нагрузку несут). Моя задача внедрить админку в сайт без ее непосредственного написания.

Comment: Вот вам пример таблицы `users`<br><br>
login, password, group - вот и все, в чем противоречия? что не так?<br><br>
в таблице group<br>
group_name, group_rights, is_admin
<br><br>
Что вас смущает не пойму...<br>
PS: как вариант is_admin - может быть в таблице пользователей. По поводу ООП - если перенести то Users - базовый класс для "простых" пользователей и "админов", исходя из этого - все пользователи должны хранится в 1ой таблице ;)

Comment: В логике это мало поможет, потому как есть самое главное-права, а они достаются по разному. Хочется чтобы пользователь в системе был полноценным, не просто логин и пароль, но и вся ветка вытекающих из типа данных, а обращаться к одному объекту. Думаю можно сделать, как вариант, два метода авторизации и сделать пару методов, которые внутри уже разруливают права. Ну а за идею плюсую. Сам на вашей стороне, только есть моменты которые уже не исправить.

Comment: Ну делайте еще одну табличку прав, права для конкретного пользователя делайте приоритетнее прав группы, все-равно не понимаю в чем проблема<br>
А то что есть что-то что нельзя исправить - не поверю никогда в жизни :)

Comment: В этом есть смысл - Вы меня наставили на путь истинный! Спасибо!)

Comment: Всегда рад помочь :)

Comment: Это фрэймворк - я не зануда %)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаем таблицу прав для групп и особенностей с полями `tinyint 1`(или ENUM 0,1 для знающих толк в извращениях), соответственно 1 - есть права, 0 - нет.
Создаем таблицу групп, делаем Foreign key по Primary key, в таблице пользователей делаем поле Group в котором тоже делаем Foreign key по Primary key таблицы групп.

Ну по БД я бы сделал как-то так. Ну а по серверному коду тут хоть Yii, хоть CodeIgniter хоть процедурный код с ноля, без разницы...

Т.е. например - во время авторизации ложим в сессию текущее значение группы, что-то типа  `$_SESSION['user_group'] = $sqlResultArray['group']` и по нему уже можем определять текущую группу, в любом случае это все уже тонкости реализации и специфик конкретных нужд

Comment: Начал отвечать не зная о том что только фронт, не совсем понял как это и почему и какой в этом смысл, не могли бы описать поподробнее?<br>
И что вы имели введу когда писали "как без этого ну никак нельзя"?

Comment: Картинку бы прикрепить!) Короче есть пользователи, которые админят сайт и есть посетители. Я хочу сделать только сайт без админки. Если авторизуется админ (через другую страничку авторизации), то ему доступно на сайте больще кнопок, чем пользователю. В свою очередь пользователи тоже разделяются по правам (у них свои права на личный кабинет).

Comment: Так а в чем проблема то? Ну сделайте для групп поле, например admin_group, соответственно - для "админских групп" ставьте 1, для остальных - 0. По этому полю и определяйте уже - что показывать и как быть :)<br>